# app crash when SDWebImageProgressiveDownload

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uitableview, sdwebimage

I am using SDWebImage library for fetching and caching images in a table view. However the app crashes due to low memory when i use the option SDWebImageProgressiveDownload.Also the library seems to be slow in downloading images. I dont think its caching them coz every time i request to fetch the same amount of time is taken to download. Has anyone encountered the same problem? Is there a solution for this?